Error: Page "/dashboard/admin/editProduct/[id]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config
I am trying to convert my Next.js web app to an Android app using @capacitor/cli and @capacitor/core. For that, I built the Next.js app using npm run build.
However, I encountered this error:
Error: Page "/dashboard/admin/editProduct/[id]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
    at D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1294:59
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 23)
    at async D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1172:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1095:124
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async build (D:\BuildTest\savehub\savehub\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:366:9)
   Collecting page data  .


But when I deploy it to Vercel, it works fine.
Here is my next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "http://localhost:3000" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, x-api-key" },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
  output: 'export',
};

export default nextConfig;


I am also using React Query to make API calls.
What should I do to resolve this error? Any help would be appreciated.
I tried removing the
output: 'export',
in next.config.js
it builds then after
i try to
npx cap sync
it shows
[error] Could not find the web assets directory: .\out.
        Please create it and make sure it has an index.html file. You can change the path of this directory in
        capacitor.config.ts (webDir option). You may need to compile the web assets for your app (typically npm run
        build). More info: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/workflow#sync-your-project

